# MYSQL: Friendly URLs sql query

Tags: php, mysql, url, seo

I want to make a query using which I can check that URL which I am making for a new video entry is not present in my db.

My current query is:

```
SELECT Count(videoid) FROM video WHERE titleurl = 'test';
```

I am storing count in a variable `$n` Then checking it using the following PHP code

```
if ($n > 0){
    return $output . "-$n";
}else{
    return $output;
}
```

But above query is creating a problem. Suppose

- 1st user submitted a video with name `Test` so the url will be `http://example.com/video/test/`
- 2nd user submitted a video with name `Test` so the url will be `http://example.com/video/test-1/` because one entry with titleurl `test` is already present, so I have added 1 in it which will be `test-1`
- 3rd user also added a video entry with name `test` but this time accoridng to my method url will be `test-1` which is wrong.

I want to solve this problem, if `test` is already present then it should be `test-1` and if another user creating a entry with name test then url should be `test-2` because test and `test-1` are already there.

Please give some method with which I can solve this issue.

Comment: `SELECT Count(videoid) FROM video WHERE titleurl LIKE 'test-%' OR titleurl = 'test';`, but that also matches things like test-me etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

friendly urls are nice, but you should always add the objects id as well, or store a unique string in the database. Check the urls here on stackoverflow, for example.

**EDIT**
I seriously doubt that google is ok with short numbers but dislikes long numbers. Here is a solution using numbers only where you must: Add another column holding the 'id' value of each test-video and create a unique index on that and titleurl:

```
ALTER TABLE video ADD COLUMN titleurl_id UNSIGNED TINYINT NOT NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_url ON video (titleurl, titleurl_id);
```

When creating a video, you need to add that value:

```
$amount = query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM video WHERE titleurl='test'");
query("INSERT INTO video(titleurl, titleurl_id) VALUES ('test', $amount + 1)");
```

You will need to pay attention to the result of your insert query, you might run into race conditions if you do it this way (that's why ids are more convenient in the url). Creating a URL:

```
$urlpart = query("
    SELECT IF(
        titleurl_id = 0,
        titleurl,
        CONCAT_WS('-', titleurl, titleurl_id)
    ) AS url FROM video");
```

Comment: I was thinking to make the urls like "<name>-<id>" `test-20345` but my seniors says that adding id with url will create problem in SEO, google doesn't love such kind of URLs who have long numbers. What should I do?

Comment: I think I have to go with `LIKE` in SQL query.

Comment: @Prashant: Ask your seniors what serious evidence they base their statements on.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is to select all urls that starts with test `... WHERE url LIKE 'test%'` and check then if `test` exists - if yes, add `-1` and again check if `test-1` exists. If yes, increase counter to `-2`..

Comment: Agree with @chronous comment and also it will be a recursive type of method, which can create problem and may slowdown the process.

Comment: On second thought, if you do `LIKE-% OR =`-query, and put all the results into an array, and then iterate that array looking for test-%d - that _might_ be a solution. Not a perfect one, but relatively fast unless you get hundreds/thousands of URLs matching the `LIKE`-query...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two fields - one for the original url, and one for your 'calculated' url.

```
$c = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE original_url = 'test'
UPDATE table SET url='test-$c' WHERE id=...
```